Are there concave up and concave down symbols in beamer?
I am looking for concave up and concave down symbols in beamer. The ones which can be scaled to use in the analysis of second derivative.
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} \mode<presentation> { \usetheme{boxes} } \begin{document} \begin{frame} \begin{tabular}{c|lcccr} $x$&$0$&\hspace{1.5cm}\ &\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{$\pi$}&\hspace{1.5cm}\ &$2\pi$\\ \hline $\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{f''(x)}$&&$-$&\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,1.00}{\vdots}&$+$&\\ \hline $f(x)$&&$\frown$& \end{tabular} \end{frame} \end{document}



Please include a sketch how the result should look like. Please also always include a test file in your questions!

Is there some bigger symbol than the one I used on the third row for f(x)? The current symbol is \frown

Please add a test file

It looks ugly, because you should add it to your question, not in comments

Thanks for the tip. I put the codes in the question.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks. I will play around with the scaling.

There are various package which provide \cup and \cap symbols in different shapes and sizes. You could pick one which you like. In the following an example with mathabx.
If you need full control over the shape of the symbol, you could draw it yourself:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \[
  \cap
  \cup
  \tikz{\draw (0,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, x radius=0.5em, y radius=0.4em];}
  \tikz{\draw (0,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-180, x radius=0.5em, y radius=0.4em];}  
  \]
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Can the symbols be stretched horizontally?

@hochoi I added a second approach which will give you full control over the shape.

The second approach is better :)

Do you mean \smile and \frown?
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

Convex: $\smile$

Concave: $\frown$

\end{frame}

\end{document}



I will try them too. Thanks!
